# bitbake recipe to include configure options

Tags: autotools, yocto, bitbake

I am using a bitbake recipe to build a NFC library https://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci. I am using following yocto recipe

```
SUMMARY = "Linux NFC stack for NCI based NXP NFC Controllers"
HOMEPAGE = ""
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://src/include/linux_nfc_api.h;endline=17;md5=42fdb99b3ff2c12f594b22a774cb7308"
SECTION = "libs"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci.git"
SRCREV = "118ea118cecda55c1b6a87d151a77b04515687df"
PV = "2.0+git${SRCPV}"
EXTRA_OECONF +="--enable-pn7150"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
inherit autotools

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libnfc_nci_linux-1.so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = "${libdir}/libnfc_nci_linux.so"
```

I want to include "--enable-pn7150" in configure options and thus I included **EXTRA_OECONF** in bitbake recipe to pass this option. But after bitbake it shows error "*configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-pn7150*". But if I compile this library without bitbake (using makefile) then configure accept this option. How can I pass "--enable-pn7150" in configure option in bitbake recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you fecth from github doens't include the PN7150, since it has been released in the commit next to the one set in SRCREV.
Also, as an advise, put a space before the two minuses. Every recipe has it, this way:

`EXTRA_OECONF = " --enable-pn7150"`